# How to get only top/most_recent 5 submissions of user in reddit using PRAW

Tags: python, reddit, praw

As mentioned in the docs,

```
    for submission in reddit.redditor('spez').submissions.top('all'):
        print(submission.title)
```

returns top 100 submissions for user `'spez'`.

How do I limit this to 10 submissions ?

Comment: maybe `reddit.redditor('spez').submissions.top('all')[:10]`? It would still retrieve all the submissions, but it would then slice the list so that you only iterated through the top 10

Comment: Yes but then the response time would be still be the same as retrieving all the submissions. Is there a way to only retrieve the top 10 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the documentation, there should be optional arguments you can put in your call to top. One of these is limit which will limit the number of entries it fetches.

Try,

```
for submission in reddit.redditor('spez').submissions.top('all', limit=10):
    print(submission.title)
```